# How to displasy a processing screen when submiting in inline edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and it is working fine. my concern is how to display a processing screen when submitting the inline edit button.

```
$(grid_selector).jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                height: "auto",
                colNames: ['LeaveTypeId', 'EmployeeId', 'Leave Type', 'Leave Act', 'Carry Forward', ' ', 'Total', 'Approved', 'Pending', 'Total'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'LeaveTypeId', index: 'LeaveTypeId', hidden: true, editable: true },
                    { name: 'EmployeeId', index: 'EmployeeId', hidden: true, editable: true },
                    { name: 'LeaveType', index: 'LeaveType' },
                    { name: 'LeaveActEntitlement', width: 120, index: 'LeaveActEntitlement', editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validate_edit }, hidedlg: true, editable: true },
                    { name: 'ForwardedEntitlement', width: 120, index: 'ForwardedEntitlement', editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validate_edit }, hidedlg: true, editable: true },
                    {
                        name: 'myac',
                        index: 'LeaveActEntitlement',
                        width: 77,
                        fixed: true,
                        sortable: false,
                        resize: false,
                        formatter: 'actions',

                        formatoptions: {
                            delbutton: false,
                            editOptions: {
                                onclickSubmit: function (params, posdata) {
                                   // function to show wait block 
                                   ShowWaitBlock();
                                },
                            },
                            onSuccess: function ( response) {
                                var jsonResponse = response.responseJSON;

                                if (showMessage(jsonResponse))
                                {
                                    $(".tooltip").hide();
                                    var data = $(grid_selector).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
                                    data[selectedRowId - 1] = jsonResponse.data;
                                    ReloadGrid(data);
                                }
                               // function to hide wait block
                               HideWaitblock();
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    { name: 'TotalEntitlement', index: 'TotalEntitlement' },
                    { name: 'Approved', index: 'Approved' },
                    { name: 'Pending', index: 'Pending' },
                    { name: 'TotalLeaveTransactions', index: 'TotalLeaveTransactions' }
                ],

                viewrecords: true,
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                ajaxRowOptions: {
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        alert("Editing");
                        // function to show processing screen
                        ShowWaitBlock();
                    }
                },
                //pager: pager_selector,
                //altRows: true,
                multiselect: true,

                multiboxonly: false,
                //loadtext:"Loading...",
                loadComplete: function() {
                    var table = this;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        updatePagerIcons(table);
                        enableTooltips(table);
                    }, 0);
                    $(".cbox").hide();
                },
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id) {
                        selectedRowId = id; // save current row ID 
                        $("#info_dialog").css('background-color', 'blue');
                        $("#info_dialog").css('display', 'none');
                    }
                },
                loadonce: false,
                editurl: '/LeaveManagement/LeaveEntitlement/EditEntitlement' ,
                autowidth: false,
                width: 1119
            }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

This alert on onClickSubmit fires. but it does not displays the waiting screen. My wait screen function works fine in everywhere on the application.
I even tried to call the function in

```
$('.ui-icon-pencil').click(function(){
   ShowWaitBlock();
});
```

even this didn't work for me.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: It doesn't give any errors. but the processing screen is not appearing. please suggest me another way to achieve this.